# orderlist is not working in PrimeFaces 3.5

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 3.5. I want to use orderList on my page. Following is my bean class.

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.UnselectEvent;

@ManagedBean
public class OrderListView {

    @ManagedProperty("#{themeService}")
    private List<String> cities;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        //Cities
        cities = new ArrayList<String>();
        cities.add("San Francisco");
        cities.add("London");
        cities.add("Paris");
        cities.add("Istanbul");
        cities.add("Berlin");
        cities.add("Barcelona");
        cities.add("Rome");
        //Themes
    }

    public List<String> getCities() {
        return cities;
    }

    public void setCities(List<String> cities) {
        this.cities = cities;
    }

    public void onSelect(SelectEvent event) {}
    public void onUnselect(UnselectEvent event) {}
    public void onReorder() {} 
}
```

And Here is my page content.

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
   xmlns:c = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:body>
   <h:form >
   <p:panel>
      <p:orderList value="#{orderListView.cities}" var="city" controlsLocation="none" itemLabel="#{city}" itemValue="#{city}" />
   </p:panel>
   </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

I am getting exception for this.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.primefaces.component.orderlist.OrderListRenderer.encodeOptions(OrderListRenderer.java:150)
at org.primefaces.component.orderlist.OrderListRenderer.encodeList(OrderListRenderer.java:109)
at org.primefaces.component.orderlist.OrderListRenderer.encodeMarkup(OrderListRenderer.java:80)
at org.primefaces.component.orderlist.OrderListRenderer.encodeEnd(OrderListRenderer.java:50)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:519)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:63)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:47)
at
```

I have tried this example from PrimeFaces showcase still its not working.
Can anybody tell me what went wrong?

Comment: Are you running PrimeFaces 3.5 on legacy JSF 1.2? The support for JSF 1.2 was dropped since  PrimeFaces 2, [see](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3574). You will need at least JSF 2.x.

Comment: sorry I am using jsf 2.0

Comment: I have tried initializing list in a constructor of some other class which is initialize on start up still its giving the same exception

Comment: Why is there a `@ManagedProperty` on `cities`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nullpointer exception that is thrown indicates that the cities list or the bean is null. Try to debug the code at see if the init() method actually fires.

I don't know what server you are using, but a restart may help to register the newly created managed bean.

**Edit 1:**

Could you try to remove @ManagedProperty("#{themeService}") from above the list and try again?

Comment: Hi Emil Kaminski, I have added breakpoint in my init(), its coming inside init and the list has all the cities.

Comment: I am getting this exception while rendering the page

Comment: Thank you @Emil Kaminski, I have removed the @ManagedProperty("#{themeService}"), and Its working.

Comment: You're welcome, please select this as the accepted answer so we can "close" this quesion

Comment: Seems like a lot of guesswork is happening here; this might be more useful as a comment